# Reading values from datafram.iloc is too slow and problem in dataframe.values

Tags: python, pandas

I use python and I have data of 35 000 rows I need to change values by loop but it takes too much time

ps: I have columns named by succes_1, succes_2, succes_5, succes_7....suces_120 so I get the name of the column by the other loop the values depend on the other column

exemple:

```
SK_1    Sk_2    Sk_5   ....   SK_120    Succes_1    Succes_2    ...   Succes_120
1        0       1             0          1            0                 0
1        1       0             1          2            1                 1

for i in range(len(data_jeux)):
    for d in range (len(succ_len)):
        ids = succ_len[d]
        if data_jeux['SK_%s' % ids][i] == 1:
             data_jeux.iloc[i]['Succes_%s' % ids]= 1+i
```

I ask if there is a way for executing this problem with the faster way I try :

```
data_jeux.values[i, ('Succes_%s' % ids)] = 1+i
```

but it returns me the following error maybe it doesn't accept string index

Comment: You should give a [mcve], with some lines and columns, so that we can load it easily and propose a solution. Without it, the question is rather off topic...

Answer (score 1):

You can define columns and then use `loc` to increment. It's not clear whether your columns are naturally ordered; if they aren't you can use `sorted` with a custom function. String-based sorting will cause `'20'` to come before `'100'`.

```
def splitter(x):
    return int(x.rsplit('_', maxsplit=1)[-1])

cols = df.columns
sk_cols = sorted(cols[cols.str.startswith('SK')], key=splitter)
succ_cols = sorted(cols[cols.str.startswith('Succes')], key=splitter)

df.loc[df[sk_cols] == 1, succ_cols] += 1
```

Comment: misread the question thought the OP wanted to increment the `SK` columns +1

Comment: @EdChum, Thanks - I borrowed your `str.startswith` much better than `df.filter`.